# How does Hinduism explain sudden sexual desire between a man and a woman from the perspective of chakras?

Tags: sex, chakras, lust

Aside from hormones, I recall feeling extreme lust for a specific girl. It did not happen with other girls; I even felt the lower chakra swadhistanas working.

How does Hinduism explain this from an 'energy' perspective? How does it work? Does it have to do with karma? Is it that if two people's swadhistana chakras have a 90% energy match that they are drawn to each other?

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work like that. *Chakras* are like energy centers at particular points of the subtile body that have an effect on the physical body and the outside world. Meditation on those particular points gives a person the *control* to manipulate those specific centers of energy that way influence both - the internal and external world. The working of certain body parts has nothing to do with chakra and energy. If you are drawn lustfully to someone, you must understand that is what a normal healthy body does. Yoga seeks to control the body and make it one with the universe.